# Trying to understand the critically damped equations of a RLC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks, damping-factor

I am trying to understand the equations of the critically damped equations of a RLC circuit [here](http://tuttle.merc.iastate.edu/ee201/topics/capacitors_inductors/RLC_transients.pdf)

I see this part on page 16

[image]

The part I do not understand is this one:

[image]

How can part of the equation be extracted and equaled to zero???

I mean,  I understand what the author is trying to do but I cannot understand where this third line comes from.

Comment: Look at the third line carefully. That's your answer..

Comment: I am reading and it says nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can part of the equation be extracted and equaled to zero???

It isn't, y is equated to \$\dfrac{dv_{tr}}{dt}+\alpha v_{tr}\$ and that is the quantity within both square brackets above the equation you have a problem with.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but you explanation is not hitting any neurons on my brain... I mean where this third line is coming from?

Comment: Check out my addition @SpaceDog

Comment: now I see it. THANKSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Andy’s answer is correct, but just to rephrase:

Suppose we take the stuff in the brackets, on the second line, and we call that *y*.

Then \$y=\dfrac{dv_{tr}}{dt}+\alpha v_{tr}\$

Now substitute both brackets of line two with *y*, and you have

\$\dfrac{dy}{dt}+\alpha y = 0\$

So, the third line is just the second line, re-written in terms of the *y* substitution.

Comment: HOLY COW! Now I see. I thought the guy was doing some black magic there, like the substitutions you do when you integrate complex stuff or something. DUH!!!!  Sorry about that. My brain was melting and I was not able to see the obvious. THANKS!!!!!!!!!!!